# Unable to setup networking to access docker container IPs from outside?

Tags: docker, networking, containers

**Context:**
I have a web server hosting a UI from which users can request for emulator instances for my product. Each emulator instance is a webapp running on nodejs. When a user requests an emulator instance from the UI, I spawn a docker container. I would like to return to the user an IP address(+port) from which this emulator container can be accessed.
Note: Presently, docker and the webserver facing the user are running on the same system.

**Problems:**
1) The default container on the docker0 network is accessible only with it's local IP address on the host. e.g. http://172.17.0.5. I can't access the container with http://localhost:32768 (container was started with -P and was assigned the port 32768). I get a message that the site can't be reached.

2) I can't use the docker host network driver because the emulator uses ports internally which I don't want to expose in the host network

3) I don't want to use the macvlan driver because I will be using up too many IPs.

Is it possibly to map various ports on the host to IPs on the docker0 subnet? If yes, how do I go about this? If this is possible I could expose the host IP and the container specific port to the user.

What is best way to give users access to the containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a `nginx` container acting as a proxy? Make your containers have same name always.

Serve new app instance:

```
docker run -d --rm --name=static_prefix__unique_id your_image
```

Have a wildcard domain:

```
unique_id.yourdomain.com
```

Or simply:

```
yourdomain.com/unique_id
```

You can dynamically proxy the request (I assume you're using port 3000 for the nodejs app):

```
proxy_pass http://static_prefix__$extractedNameFromRequestUri:3000
```

Docker will do the hard job for you and route traffic from outside to the `static_prefix__unique_id` container.